# Wordpress Custom URL Rewrites

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have links in my site that pass queries to pages that query from an external database. This works fine e.g.

```
mysite.com/catalog/?tl=flooring
```

however i want to rewrite this url to appear as

```
mysite.com/catalog/flooring
```

Ive tried modifying the rewrite rules in wordpress but it always displays the index page

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array','wp_insertMyRewriteRules');
add_filter('query_vars','wp_insertMyRewriteQueryVars');
add_filter('init','flushRules');

// Remember to flush_rules() when adding rules
function flushRules(){
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

// Adding a new rule
function wp_insertMyRewriteRules($rules)
{
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules['(catalog)/([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)$'] = '/catalog/?tl=$matches[2]';
    return $newrules + $rules;
}

// Adding the id var so that WP recognizes it
function wp_insertMyRewriteQueryVars($vars)
{
    array_push($vars, 'id');
    return $vars;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rewrite rules in WordPress don't quite work like how you're expecting them to. All rewrite rules map to a file handler (almost always `index.php`), not another URL.

Here is a shortened code example;

```
$rules['catalog/(.*)/?'] = 'index.php?pagename=catalog&tl=$matches[1]';
array_push($query_vars, 'tl'); // note query var should match your query string
```

This would map `catalog/whatever` to the WordPress page 'catalog', and pass along the query var 'tl'. You could create a page template for 'catalog', then pick up the value of 'tl' using `get_query_var('tl')`.

Also avoid using query vars like `id` - use something more unique (like 'tl') to avoid clashes with WordPress.

And **don't** flush rules on every init! It's bad practice, and will write to `.htaccess` and call database updates on **every** page load!

WordPress will always flush permalinks whenever you update a post or your permalink structure (simply update your permalinks when you make changes to your code).

Comment: would it be possible to redirect to a child page? I have put the postname into pagename, but it's actually redirecting the page.

Comment: If it's a child page, `pagename` should be the slug **path** - for example `pagename=parentname/childname`

Answer (score 2):

[This article over at Raazorlight](http://www.rlmseo.com/blog/passing-get-query-string-parameters-in-wordpress-url/) goes into a bit more detail on the process of grabbing querystrings and URL rewriting in WP.

Also, check the comments there to see why calling `flushRules()` may not be necessary if you re-save permalinks. Optionally, `flushRules()` can be called just once during plugin activation callback.

Digging deeper, commenter 'pmdci' links over to an instructive post/saga on the related topic of *passing a query to a custom post type using a custom taxonomy*.