# WordPress and ReWriteRule

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a product-details template in my theme that handles display for different products based on the URL.

By default, WordPress will allow a number to be passed to the template page by appending to the URL: `product-details/3/`

However, I want to make this to be more SEO Friendly using a slug: `product/sandals`. Yet, when I do so, WordPress no longer finds the page by default.

I tried the following ReWriteRule with no luck.

```
RewriteRule ^product/([\w\-]+)/?$ product-details/?slug=$1 [L]
```

How can I have this custom slug sent to the template. I would prefer to keep everything in WordPress, but am willing to add the `ReWriteRule`.

Comment: How should the slug be sent to Wordpress? In other words, what do you need the final form of the URL (as seen by Wordpress/the template) to be? Note that if Wordpress can only accept a number, you won't be able to convert the slug to the number just using mod_rewrite.

Comment: @David I understand I can't convert the slug. I am happy to read the slug from `$_GET` as implied by the attempted ReWriteRule

Comment: OK, just making sure you knew ;-) In that case I'm not sure what's going on. your rewrite rule seems like is should work, assuming you put it in an `.htaccess` file in the directory corresponding to the URL location of your WP installation. For instance, if the product pages are accessible at e.g. `example.com/store/product-details/3/` make sure you put the rule in `${DOCUMENT_ROOT}/store/.htaccess`. You might need to add `RewriteBase /store/` but I thought it should work without that. Can you try enabling the rewrite log?

Comment: You cannot do this in your `.htaccess` file as Wordpress has it's own 'rewrite' system. It's not clear to me exactly what you want to do, but this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307352/wordpress-custom-url-rewrites) or the documentation for the `WP_Rewrite` class (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Rewrite) may be helpful.

Comment: @Richard, thanks for the references - they put me on the right track. @David, this would be an option if my page were *outside* the WP structure. However, these pages are templates of the theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to **Richard** for answering this in the OP comments. I've highlighted the resource for completeness and to mark this question answered.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Rewrite